# Massive spike in "Excessive slow frames" from Android 12

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-vitals

Android Vitals is reporting a high rate of "Excessive slow frames" in Android 12 and 13. The same version has been running for 3 months+... Is there any known issue or something that I should take care of in those Android versions?

It basically goes from ~4% (which I think is still a bit high but acceptable) to ~28%!

Same app version... Jetpack Compose.

[image: Android 11]

[image: Android 12]

EDIT:
Turns out Android 8.0 and 8.1 is even worse! So basically the app has issues on Android 8.0, 8.1 and 12+. Only 9, 10 and 11 are ok.
[image: Android 8.0 and 8.1]

Comment: Did you update your app to latest ```Compose Version 1.5.1``` because It has a lot of changes in that which may improve your app perfomance

Comment: Yes, I also tried to update to 1.6 alpha to see if anything changes, but I need some days to get vitals to update

Comment: Because I'm facing issue in New Navigation Library. And it's dropping some frames as compared to old one

Comment: What is your excessive slow/frozen frames in vitals? Which compose version are you using?

Comment: you doesn't fix prematurely performance issues, check how your widget performs with lifecycle compose.